# How to find coefficients for a possible exponential approximation

Tags: matlab, octave, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have data like this:

```
y = [0.001
     0.0042222222
     0.0074444444
     0.0106666667
     0.0138888889
     0.0171111111
     0.0203333333
     0.0235555556
     0.0267777778
     0.03]
```

and

```
x = [3.52E-06
     9.72E-05
     0.0002822918
     0.0004929136
     0.0006759156
     0.0008199029
     0.0009092797
     0.0009458332
     0.0009749509
     0.0009892005]
```

and I want `y` to be a function of `x` with y = a(0.01 − b*n^−cx).

What is the best and easiest computational approach to find the best combination of the coefficients `a`, `b` and `c` that fit to the data?

Can I use Octave?

Comment: (1) is `n` a constant? You could do an OLS curve fit.

Comment: yes! n is a constant. Actualy, ignore b. How can I find a and c?

Comment: Ordinary least squares. In your case you will have to take logs first to make your function linear (linear in the coefficients that is). And then you can use this function: http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/ols.html

Comment: And how to do it with matlab?

Comment: That `0.01` term is going to be pesky though... maybe you'll just have to not take logs

Comment: Matlab or Octave? If Matlab, what toolboxes do you have?

Comment: I can install matlab 2015 with default stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function

> y = a(0.01 − b*n<sup>−cx</sup>)

is in quite a specific form with 4 unknowns. In order to estimate your parameters from your list of observations I would recommend that you simplify it

> y = β<sub>1</sub> + β<sub>2</sub><sup>β<sub>3</sub>x</sup>

This becomes our objective function and we can use ordinary least squares to solve for a good set of betas.

In default Matlab you could use [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) to find these β parameters (lets call it our parameter vector, ***β***), and then you can use simple algebra to get back to your `a`, `b`, `c` and `n` (assuming you know either `b` or `n` upfront). In Octave I'm sure you can find an equivalent function, I would start by looking in here: http://octave.sourceforge.net/optim/index.html.

We're going to call `fminsearch`, but we need to somehow pass in your observations (i.e. `x` and `y`) and we will do that using anonymous functions, so  like example 2 from the docs:

```
beta = fminsearch(@(x,y) objfun(x,y,beta), beta0) %// beta0 are your initial guesses for beta, e.g. [0,0,0] or [1,1,1]. You need to pick these to be somewhat close to the correct values.
```

And we define our objective function like this:

```
function sse = objfun(x, y, beta)
    f = beta(1) + beta(2).^(beta(3).*x);
    err = sum((y-f).^2); %// this is the sum of square errors, often called SSE and it is what we are trying to minimise!
end
```

So putting it all together:

```
y= [0.001; 0.0042222222; 0.0074444444; 0.0106666667; 0.0138888889; 0.0171111111; 0.0203333333; 0.0235555556; 0.0267777778; 0.03];
x= [3.52E-06; 9.72E-05; 0.0002822918; 0.0004929136; 0.0006759156; 0.0008199029; 0.0009092797; 0.0009458332; 0.0009749509; 0.0009892005];
beta0 = [0,0,0];

beta = fminsearch(@(x,y) objfun(x,y,beta), beta0)
```

Now it's your job to solve for `a`, `b` and `c` in terms of `beta(1)`, `beta(2)` and `beta(3)` which you can do on paper.

Comment: I found that a possible approximation is y= 0.001 -ae^-bx. Can I apply the same method?

Comment: of course just change one line: `f = 0.001 - beta(1).*exp(-beta(2).*x));` Personally, unless your `a` or `b` are a meaningful physical SCALAR quantities, I would rather use  `f = 0.001 + beta(1).*exp(beta(2).*x));` and just have negative `beta`s

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't compute your code. but i found I can use cftool.

Comment: `cftool` will have a code generation option on it that will create matlab script code for you which you can then compare against mine. Also, `cftool` is not in default Matlab but in the curve fitting toolbox. It would have been helpful information to know that you had access to this toolbox for answering this question...